# Child click event affecting parent event

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="alert ('parent event')">
        <td>
             <input type="button" name="click me" value="I'm a button" id="click me" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I have a click event bound on the `tr`, now if I click on the button, that click event  on the `tr` is also triggered.

How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: @warl0ck is any event attached in javascript? not the inline one

Comment: Just use `.event.stopPropogation()` to prevent the event from bubbling upwards, as @Pilot mentioned.

Comment: @Pilot The real code is more complicated. So I made a minimal case here

Answer (score 2):

Change your input ID to `click-me` (without spaces), then put this between script tags:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('click-me').onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you can simply put this code in the onclick attribute:

```
<input type="button" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwk38/

Answer (score 1):

you can solve like below;

html:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="trAlert()" bgcolor="#cccccc" width="300" height="300">
        <td>
             <input type="button" onclick="btnAlert()" name="click me" value="I'm a button" id="click me" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
function trAlert()
{
    alert('tr');
}

function btnAlert()
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('btn');   
}
```

see the demo here --->http://jsfiddle.net/Junkie/kZ6J6/

Answer (score 0):

> In bubbling the event is first captured and handled by the inner most
>   element and then propagated to outer elements.

You should stop event from getting [bubbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing),

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="alert('parent click')">
        <td>
            <input onclick="event.stopPropagation();" type="button" name="click me" value="I'm a button" id="click me" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmVWp/)**

Answer (score -1):

Add an onclick handler too to the `input`, on which the callback contains `event.stopPropagation()`

```
function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```